# how to see iOS device logs in Console app using os_log

Tags: ios, logging, console

I want to test my app when it is not launched via Xcode, but rather by launching directly from the springboard. And I want to see log messages as I do that.

I'm not having any trouble seeing console logs for the *simulator* using `os_log`. It's great, because my category and subsystem let me filter to see exactly the messages I want to see in the Console app:

[image]

Now I want to do this on my *device*. I can see my connected device listed in the Console app:

[image]

But I don't see any of my app's `os_log` or `print` messages in the Console app. Is this just not a supported thing? Is there a way to log to the Console app from my device? Is there *any* way to log from my app running independently on the device?

**EDIT** Curiouser and curiouser. Now I'm able to see *some* of my app's `os_log` messages in the Console while the app runs independently on the device:

[image]

The catch, however, is that word "some". It seems to start working for a while and then it just mysteriously stops again. It's as if the pipeline from the device to the Console is unreliable.

So now the question becomes: is there any way to log *reliably* from my app running independently on the device?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but a large part of the trick seems to be this:

In Xcode's Devices and Simulators window, locate the device and *show the console display* by tapping the tiny button at the lower left.

[image]

It appears that this somehow opens the floodgates and allows the stream of log events to pass through to the Console app. It still isn't 100% reliable; eventually the stream can be mysteriously shut off, and I have the impression that events are randomly omitted now and then. But it seems to be a *sine qua non* for getting the stream to flow at all.

Comment: I am using Xcode 14.0.1 and am not seeing this, has this been removed?

Comment: @CyberMew That was five years ago; the Xcode interface has greatly changed since then. Maybe this is replaced by the Open Console button at the top.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have enabled the **Include Info Messages** & **Include Debug Messages** from **Console.app > Action** menu.

[image]